# Mobile Automation Testing: To be displayed in PC

Tags: python, android, selenium

I'm Running a mobile automation script, I have connected my mobile with PC using ADB and running it through appium, so when I run my script the testing occurs in the Mobile, is there any way I can see the mobile screen in my PC.

Answer (score 0):

> Vysor is best software to see mobile screen on PC.  [Vysor](https://www.vysor.io/)
>
> Download and install on PC. Your mobile phone must have developer
>   option ON.

- USB Debugging On

> Enjoy it
>   [image]

Answer (score 0):

We can use Android inbuilt casting option to mirror the device on PC.

On your PC go to
settings > system > Projecting to PC
[Projecting to PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZFon.png)

Now select -  'Optional Features' > 'Add a Features' > select 'Wireless Display' (install it if it is not installed)

[Wireless Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVLXk.png)

Now select 'Available everywhere' from dropdown

[Available everywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTdSc.png)

Now your PC is ready to connect with Android.
Select 'Smart View' option from notification center of android device, this start the screen mirroring of android device on PC.

[Smart View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDsWl.png)